# How to create an XBL control that saves data in two elements?

Tags: xsd, orbeon, xforms, xbl

I'm trying to tell Orbeon to group 2 fields together in order to capture 2 values as in:
Pounds & Ounces.

```
<xs:complexType name="rpm-weight">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="weight-lbs" type="rpm-weight-lbs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="weight-oz" type="rpm-weight-oz"   minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

How can I tell Orbeon that when selecting rpm-weight, it will generate 2 text boxes?

Comment: Is this with Form Builder, or custom XForms? And you want two text boxes but storing the value in a single XML element or attribute? Please provide details.

Comment: Actually, I will be using xbl. I would like to save the values into 2 separate values. What we want to do is when selecting a custom "weight control" which would add 2 textfields (one for pounds and the other one for ounces). Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an XBL component is the way to go, which might be tricky if this is the first time you're doing this. A few pointers:

- So you can use it in Form Builder, your component needs to bind to one element (with `ref`). The name of the element will be the name given by form authors to the control in Form Builder (assuming they're not using a custom instance).
- Form Builder will create one element in the instance for the control. Since your control needs to have sub-elements, you need to tell Form Builder about those. You can do that using the `fb:metadata/fb:template/fb:instance`. See for instance how this is done in [`autocomplete.xbl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/autocomplete/autocomplete.xbl). E.g. that part of the metadata will look as follows.

Example Form Builder metadata for the XBL:

```
<fb:metadata xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
    ...
    <fb:templates>
        <fb:instance>
            <weight-lbs/>
            <weight-oz/>
        </fb:instance>
        <fb:view>
            ...
       </fb:view>
    </fb:templates>
</fb:metadata>
```